# How to increase concurrent websocket connections in play framework

Tags: websocket, playframework, akka, akka-http

I am setting up a play framework based server where I want to accept a huge number of concurrent websocket connections. In terms of resources, I don't see any bottleneck but my server always maxes out at 4k connections.

I am using a 2core/8gb centos 7 machine and have also bumped up the file descriptor count to 1000000.

/etc/security/limits.conf:

process_username  soft nofile 1000000"

process_username  hard nofile 1000000

After 4k connections, I see that it can't accept any new connections.
[logger="akka.io.TcpListener"] Accept error: could not accept new connection
java.io.IOException: Too many open files

Is there any configuration/setting in play's akka http server that is prohibiting large number of websocket connections?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117606/wsclient-too-many-open-files?

Comment: @Vamsi - thanks, but that's a websocket client side setting. my question is for the server side where I want to accept large number of WS connections.

Comment: do you have a sample code snippet to share?

Answer (score 1):

I found out. The issue was that FD values from ulimits will not be honored if the program is started as a systemd service.

In order to fix this add below attribute to the systemd unit file

[Service]

LimitNOFILE=100000  (if you want unlimited you can also use "infinity")